# How to create c++ assignment operator for =0

Tags: c++, constructor, comparator

In c++, a pointer type (`void*`/`int*`/`char*`) can be initialized with a value of 0 without type casting, but this doesn't work for any other value. Is it possible to instill the same behavior into a defined class? An `=0` constructor, or an `==0` comparator? For clarification, I'm attempting to add syntax such that my n-dimensional vector class can be assigned to a zero vector with `vec<n> dir = 0`

Edit: using void* as the type of a constructor argument does in fact work, is this the best way to achieve this though?

Comment: Please explain how this is a duplicate? Reading through the recommended thread I'm just as confused as I was coming into this, and it didn't establish a method to achieve my goal. What's with questions on this website being so quickly shut down???

Comment: This looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @molbdnilo "_You can't add implicit conversions from literal 0_" ? probably you wanted to say "can" rather than "can't"

Comment: Please note that I didnt "shut down" your quesiton. I flagged it as dupe, because I think 2/3 of your question is answered in the dupe. However, if you dont agree, I happily reopen it

Comment: @molbdnilo I'd like the ability to assign my n-dimension vector class such as `vec3 dir = 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion from literal `0` to `nullptr`, and the type of `nullptr` is `nullptr_t`.

Thus, the following works the way you want:

```
// Needed for nullptr_t
#include <cstddef> 

struct A
{
    A(std::nullptr_t) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a = 0;
}
```

Of course, this also means that `A a = nullptr` is valid, but perhaps you can live with that...

It's possible that you can accomplish this without the indirection through `nullptr_t` with some modern `constexpr` and template shenanigans.

Comment: bonus points for reminding me of both constexpr and - as you put it - template shenanigans. I looked into it briefly after you mentioned it but for now I'll go for the null_ptr option because intellisense seems to be a big fan.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a constructor that accepts *only* the literal value 0. There are a couple of things that get close.

```
#include <cstddef>

class Foo
{
    Foo(); // Construct from nothing at all
    Foo(std::nullptr_t) // Construct from the null pointer value
};
```

Which are used respectively

```
Foo foo_default;
Foo foo_null = nullptr;
```

Because 0 is also a null pointer value, you can use the `std::nullptr_t` overload with that.

```
Foo foo_zero = 0; // calls Foo(std::nullptr_t)
```

Comment: @L.F. I tried this, and didn't seem to be able to work - my class was either accepting nullptr_t as well or refusing 0 because it was ambiguous as to which constructor to use. If you can get a piece of short example code to work it would be much appreciated

Comment: @bruno That comment was actually in response to a follow up suggestion that L.F. commented which didn't seem to work. The original answer does in fact work, and was my original pick for the answer, I only swapped it because I thought the other answer was a little clearer as to what worked and why :)